# Self-sizing cell did not updated its height when the imageView inside it was set the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sdwebimage

I encountered an annoying issue in my app so I made a demo for this for convenience:

There are two **UIViewController**s A & B. B is pushed from the A and  contains an **UITableView** which is using self-sizing cell. In the **UITableViewCell** there is an **UIImageView** which set its top, leading, bottom and trailing constraint to the cell. So when the image of that ImageView is set, cell height will be auto determined.

However, when the B is pushed the first time and update its content, the cell height is not correct. But if pop B then push B again, the cell height will be correct.

So in my app, each scene like B can not get the right cell size if not be pushed the second time.

Related code is as below. The whole demo can be found in [Github](https://github.com/highsun16/WiredImageSize)

```
#import "AnotherViewController.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "UIImage+Ex.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

static NSString * const kImageUrl = @"http://img02.tooopen.com/images/20151228/tooopen_sy_152967398112.jpg";

@implementation AnotherViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    __weak typeof(CustomCell) *wCell = cell;
    [cell.bigImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kImageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_cover"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage gs_scaledImageWithWidth:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds.size.width image:image];
        wCell.bigImageView.image = scaledImage;
        [wCell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the table, not the cell.
The table view has some feature, that just updates the row heights.
Just call this methods one after another:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: How can I forget that method! It works~ But I'm still wondering what happened when calling beginUpdates. I used to call [self.view layoutSubviews] and thought it would make the tableView to redraw. However, nothing happened.

Comment: layoutSubviews: will not work. Moreover you are not allowed to call that method. If you need to relayout the view you should call setNeedsLayout: or layoutIfNeeded: